# Got error while using onclick in <a href> tag using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview

I  tried to access a ListView function from client side by using onclick in `<a href>`tag. But it resulted in an error like this:

> No overload for 'ListView1_ItemEditing' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

```
<a href="#" onServerClick="ListView1_ItemEditing" runat="server">
    <img src="../admin/images/editbtn.png"alt="editbtn" class="editimgbtn" id="editdelete"/>
</a>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //contents
}
```

I know I can access this by using a `LinkButton`, but I need to use `<a href>`instead of that, and the tag is set inside a `ListView`. So how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method signature. The signature must be:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemEditing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //contents
}
```

By the way, why do you think you need to use an `<a href>` tag? An [ImageButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton(v=vs.110).aspx) control would be more appropriate:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" OnClick="ListView1_ItemEditing"
ImageUrl="../admin/images/editbtn.png"
CssClass="editimgbtn" Id="editdelete" />
```